# Is there a replacement for Ruby Facets library?

Tags: ruby

I know Ruby Facets is a library full of extensions for Ruby classes, etc. But:

1. Is it still active?
2. Where is there *proper* documentation for it? (I cannot seem to find anything comprehensive)
3. If this project has "died", is there a fork under a different name or a continuation project with the same code base?

Thanks.

Comment: It is still active. 3.0.0 was just released in Dec '14. It may seem inactive simply b/c at this point changes are typically infrequent and minor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your questions:

1. It doesn't seem to be very active - the [github repository](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/tree/master) hasn't been modified in a year.
2. There's good documentation [here](http://www.omniref.com/?q=facets).  In fact, I've switched to omniref for nearly ALL my ruby questions - whoever made it posted it on [r/ruby](http://www.reddit.com/r/ruby) recently and it's actually very good.
3. Not sure about that.  Inactive != dead, but it's certainly not very active.

Comment: dax, I wasn't aware of OmniRef. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Is it still active?

Doesn't look like, no [commits for 1 year](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/commits) now, [no build has ever passed](https://travis-ci.org/rubyworks/facets/builds), [no ruby 2.0.0 support](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/blob/master/.travis.yml) intention there and last gem release [2.9.3](http://rubygems.org/gems/facets) dates December 31, 2011.

I tried to run the tests on my ruby 1.9.3-p484 and got the same error during `bundle install` that the equivalent [travis build](https://travis-ci.org/rubyworks/facets/jobs/11654577#L35)

```
#=> No such file or directory - .ruby from
#=>   /home/travis/build/rubyworks/facets/facets.gemspec:33:in `initialize'
```

> 2) Where is there proper documentation for it?

All i could find was at [rubydoc.info](http://rubydoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/index) but you can consider the tests as documentation too. They are divided in Ruby [core extensions](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/tree/master/test/core) and Ruby [stdlib extensions](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/tree/master/test/standard)

> 3) If it's not "alive", is there a good equivalent or replacement?

I think Rails component [ActiveSupport](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html) sort of apply as an equivalent. You can look around for alternatives at [The Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/facets) but always look at the core first or search/ask in stackoverflow the best way to do something since facets may probably not be the best option.

> 4) Does it worth it? (added by me ;)

I doubt it, there seems to be plenty of useful stuff on facets but i have just looked around and i can find an equivalent way to do some of the stuff it does, e.g.

Facets `Array#divide` "Divide on matching pattern"

```
ary = ['a1','b1','a2','b2']

# With facets
ary.divide(/^a/)
  #=> [['a1','b1'],['a2','b2']]

# With ruby alone (>= 1.9.3)
ary.slice_before(/^a/).to_a
  #=> [['a1','b1'],['a2','b2']]
```

Facets `Array#merge` to merge 2 arrays without duplicates

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [3,4,5]

# With facets
a.merge(b)   #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# With ruby alone
a | b        #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
(a + b).uniq #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I do agree with @dax, just posting this as an answer anyway since it doesn't fit in a comment and took me some research ;)